# Fancybox: Append to div, not body

Tags: modal-dialog, append, fancybox, parent

I'd like to have fancybox open a window that's 100% width/height of the link's parent div, not the body. Any pointers on how to achieve this?

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            padding: 0,
            margin: 10,
            maxWidth: '500px',
            maxHeight: '250px',
            fitToView: true,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            autoSize: true,
            closeClick: false,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            closeEffect: 'fade',
            speedIn: 100,
            speedOut: 100
    });
```

html

```
<h2>Tools &amp; Resources</h2>
<h3>Valuable industry insights from us to you — for free.</h3>


<div class="article nthChild-1 firstChild">
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="title">Rates are changing. What’s your game plan? <span class="cta"><a href="/home/tools/rates-changing" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" target="_top">Read&nbsp;more</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article nthChild-2">
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="title">Stay up to date on industry insights.<br> <span class="cta"><a href="/home/tools/industry-insights" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" target="_top">Read&nbsp;more</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article nthChild-3">
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="title">How to identify a Millennial.<br> <span class="cta"><a href="/home/tools/identify-millenial" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" target="_top">Read&nbsp;more</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article nthChild-4">
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="title">Retail success at the counter, the window, and the screen. <span class="cta"><a href="/home/tools/retail-success" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" target="_top">Read&nbsp;more</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article nthChild-5">
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="title">Consumers are talking about...<br> <span class="cta"><a href="/home/tools/consumers-are-talking" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" target="_top">Read&nbsp;more</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article nthChild-6 lastChild">
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="title">Build a winning culture that works.<br> <span class="cta"><a href="/home/tools/build-winning-culture" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" target="_top">Read&nbsp;more</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Here's a pen [link](http://codepen.io/fsodergren/pen/akKoBY). I'd like it to stay within the bounds of .container, instead of the window. Any ideas?

Comment: I am afraid you need to paste the code in your post (links may become obsolete and your question/answer meaningless)

Answer (score 0):

Use the API option `parent` pointing to the selector of the container you want append fancybox to like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        parent: "#wrap"
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

assuming that you have a container (`<div>`) with `id="wrap"`

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

see **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5nh8rg1x/)**

Comment: That's how i'd have though it should work, but hadn't gotten it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/2jru2ybs/

Comment: @FredSodergren: the wrapper needs a relative position http://jsfiddle.net/2jru2ybs/1/ you may need more CSS work to make it work the way you want though, but the `parent` option is the correct answer ;)